# Is there a way for me to track my weight on Fitocracy?

Tags: fitocracy

I am a dedicated Fitocracy user -- I faithfully input my workouts and my weight for that day each time I work out.

I noticed that I can track my fitness as far as what I can lift, longest run, etc. in my profile. Is there a way for me to see my weight loss/progression as well?

Comment: I agree, this is the feature I was searching for too, let us know when it's ready!

Answer (score 8):

I'm a developer at Fitocracy so I figure I can answer this for you!

You can currently log your weight anytime you want, or during each workout tracked, or both.

On the website you can change your weight at any time by hitting the picture of you on the top right, clicking Account Settings in the dropdown and clicking Weight.

On the website you can also set your weight at the bottom of the track page right above the submit workout button.

On the iPhone you can edit your weight by clicking on the You tab (bottom right in the bottom dashboard) and click on the weight box (bottom left box on the page).

While we currently have logs and graphs of your workouts on the Performance tab, we do not currently offer a historical view for your weight, but this will be coming soon in the next year.

Comment: Hi, Kasra. You said it's going to be done this year. Is that ready yet? How can I track my weight using Android app?

Comment: @OlegSakharov Sadly I got sidetracked by doing Android (because that wasn't on the timeline) which ended up putting everything else I was doing out of the projected timeline. Weight logs aren't on the site yet. Weight tracking on Android isn't there yet, but it's #3 on my todo list.

Comment: What's the #1 and #2?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi checking back in 3 years later. How about now? :)